# Indexable Web Directories - PCI

Tags: security

I have failed my PCI scan and one of the issues is, "Indexable Web Directories". This included `/errors/`, `/icons/`, `/icons/small/` etc. How do I resolve this without causing issues with my storefront?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `robots.txt`

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /errors
Disallow: /icons
```

Make sure you also have this in your `.htaccess`

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Does the `Options -Indexes` belong at the end of the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: I would put it near the top, but its position should not matter, as Apache processes the entire .htaccess file each time.